# How to read data from ethernet through lan cable

Tags: networking, sniffing

I want to read raw ethernet data from a PC.  What software can I use to capture data to and from a TCP/IP server?

In our project we have a [PLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller) that has an ethernet RJ45 socket and serial RS485 plug. In order to control the PLC, we have to capture the data from PLC so that we can work out what commands it is able to transmit and accept.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please refer to the FAQ, and then edit your question to clarify it, otherwise it will be closed.

Comment: I also would like to suggest that you don't ask programming questions on [SU]. We have a site for programming, which is [SO], but in order to ask there, you should really clarify your post and add details. (And maybe use proper capitalization and spelling)

Comment: I have hopefully edited your question to make it more clear as to what you are trying to achieve.  If what I have changed makes it radically different from what you are trying to do please edit it as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) should suit your requirements.